# How to fix regex Python to find address?

Tags: python, regex

I have some regex pattern to check if string is address:

```
def isAddress(line):
    line = str(line)
    splitted = line.split(" ")
    
    if len(splitted) > 2:
        patternUsa = r"^(\d{3,})\s?(\w{0,5})\s([a-zA-Z]{2,30})\s([a-zA-Z]{2,15})\.?\s?(\w{0,5})$"
        pattern1 = r"^([A-ZÄÖÜ][a-zäöüß]+(([.] )|( )|([-])))+[1-9][0-9]{0,3}[a-z]?$"
        pattern2 = r"^\d+\s[A-z]+\s[A-z]+.*"
        pattern3 = r"^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){2,6}"
        
        p1 = re.fullmatch(patternUsa, line)
        p2 = re.fullmatch(pattern1, line)
        p3 = re.fullmatch(pattern3, line)

        return p1 or p2 or p3
    else:
        return False
```

Problem is these patterns match the following string: `12 / 11 / 2002`.

I tried to check after split how much parts are numeric:

```
isNum(string):
  return re.findall(r'^[-+]?[0-9]+$', string)

splitted = line.split(" ")

if len(splitted) > 1:
   if isNum(splitted[0].strip()) and isNum(splitted[1].strip()) and isNum(splitted[2].strip()):
 print("No address")
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This pattern `pattern3 = r"^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){2,6}"` is a broad match repeating 2-6 times non whitespace chars between whitespace chars and will match `12 / 11 / 2002` but also for example `! @ #` Can you update your question with strings that should and should not match?

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach with `isNum`? BTW, [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).